# Description Item Spacing

Tags: spacing, lists, description

I've following `latex` code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
  \item[days] {\footnotesize sunday, monday}
  \item[months] {\footnotesize january, february}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

This produces:
[image]

How can I reduce the spacing between items?

Tried:

```
\begin{description}[itemsep=0pt]
```

This fails compiling on my system (Macbook pro):

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.4   \item[days]
                  {\footnotesize sunday, monday}
?
```

LaTex Version:

```
➜  helloworld git:(master) ✗ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.29; using libpng 1.6.29
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 3.04
```

I'm just starting out, I tried searching on this site and google, but couldn't figure it out. Would be grateful if anyone can help.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 1):

Found out, had to add package:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
```